# Objective-C EXC_BAD_ACCESS on Completion Handler

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method with a completion handler, here is how I am calling it:

```
[dataSource.areaData GetPDFFileData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",encodedUrlStr] completion:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {

//do whatever

}];
```

But I get a fatal error when I call this method:`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` I can see the result is being populated which is good, but I dont knwo what I am doing wrong here...here is the method defined in .h file

```
-(void)GetPDFFileData:(NSString *)PDFFile completion:(void (^) (NSArray * result,NSError * error))completionBlock;
```

and here is the full method in my .m file:

```
-(void)GetPDFFileData:(NSString *)PDFFile completion:(void (^) (NSArray * result,NSError * error))completionBlock{


    NSString *FileBrowserRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?PDFFile=%@",kIP,PDFFile];
    NSURL *JSONURL = [NSURL URLWithString:FileBrowserRequestString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:JSONURL];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                      {
                                          NSError *myError;
                                          NSArray *tableArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&myError]];

                                          completionBlock(tableArray,myError);

                                      }];
    [dataTask resume];

}
```

Am I calling the completion handler wrong?

Here is my backtrace:

```
* thread #2, queue = 'NSOperationQueue 0x16d247f0 :: NSOperation 0x18053ab0 (QOS: LEGACY)', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x12)
    frame #0: 0x20d93a76 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 22
    frame #1: 0x20da06ae libobjc.A.dylib`objc_storeStrong + 22
  * frame #2: 0x00062428 SchedulingiPadApplication`__51-[LHFileBrowser tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]_block_invoke((null)=<unavailable>, result=@"1 element", error=0x00000000) at LHFileBrowser.m:183
    frame #3: 0x00066708 SchedulingiPadApplication`__40-[LHJSonData GetPDFFileData:completion:]_block_invoke((null)=0x38739228, data=0x17b17c00, response=0x16f8d710, error=0x00000000) at LHJSonData.m:328
    frame #4: 0x21af3280 CFNetwork`__75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 16
    frame #5: 0x21b02a6a CFNetwork`__49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 278
    frame #6: 0x21dfd678 Foundation`__NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 8
    frame #7: 0x21d5e5f2 Foundation`-[NSBlockOperation main] + 146
    frame #8: 0x21d50bc8 Foundation`-[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 768
    frame #9: 0x21dff930 Foundation`__NSOQSchedule_f + 192
    frame #10: 0x00398492 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_drain + 2014
    frame #11: 0x00390de0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 284
    frame #12: 0x00399974 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 420
    frame #13: 0x003997ce libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread3 + 102
    frame #14: 0x2131db28 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 1024
    frame #15: 0x2131d718 libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 8
```

These are some lines of code before GetPDFFileData

```
NSString *PDFPath = [[[[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"FTP\\"] lastObject];

        NSString *encodedUrlStr = [PDFPath urlencode];

        NSString *PDFFile = [[[[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\"] lastObject];
```

Comment: What specific line is it crashing on? Can you provide a backtrace?

Comment: Its crashing right on this line: `[dataSource.areaData GetPDFFileData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",encodedUrlStr] completion:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {` the API is returning bytes of a full PDF file and there alot of bytes, so my end goal is collect all the bytes from the API and don't do anything until its complete.

Comment: What's the backtrace? (type `bt` in lldb to generate it)

Comment: Where do I find that?

Comment: When it's crashed, type `bt` into lldb

Comment: Looks like something funky is going on on line 183 of `LHFileBrowser.m`. What's going on in that area of that source file?

Comment: Since the actual crash is occurring in `objc_storeStrong`, which is ARC trying to retain something, it's possible that you might have an invalid object somewhere earlier in your code before you call `GetPDFFileData:` and that's getting captured by the completion block.

Comment: line 183 is this line `[dataSource.areaData GetPDFFileData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",encodedUrlStr] completion:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {`

Comment: I updated my question with some lines of code before calling GetPDFFileData

Comment: Try running it with zombie detection turned on—option-click the Run button, click Diagnostics, and turn on the check box for enabling zombies. This should cause it to give us some much more helpful debug information.

Comment: Completion blocks work like traditional C variables, so you should check if they're not null before invoking the block: `if (completionBlock) completionBlock(tableArray, myError);`. `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` basically tells you that you tried to access some invalid memory (almost certainly a `NULL` pointer). It could also mean that the execution of that particular block failed (crashed). Where does `kIP` come from?

Comment: kIP is a string with the URL to the API

Comment: Running it with zombie detection turned on

Comment: I do not see any difference

Comment: Nothing got logged to the console about a message having been sent to a zombie?

Comment: Nope, nothing about zombie

Comment: I checked the box under Memory Management called 'Zombie Objects'

Comment: Ughhh. Let's test my hypothesis about it being something captured by the block. Comment out everything inside the completion block you send to `GetPDFFileData:`, and put an `NSLog` in there (so the log is the only thing in the block). See if the log gets logged or if it still crashes.

Comment: I just ran the code and all of this came up in my console https://jpst.it/1buzL

Comment: Oy. Is the log you added in there somewhere (if you search for the text of it)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165929/discussion-between-user979331-and-charles-srstka).

Comment: Also, @AlejandroIván's hypothesis might be correct; try putting the execution of `completionBlock` inside an `if` statement and see if that makes it go away (it's good practice anyway).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `completionBlock` is not retained, so by the time the `dataTask` finishes, it no longer exists.

You should retain it, for example by keeping it in a dictionary and then removing it when the task completes.

```
-(void)GetPDFFileData:(NSString *)PDFFile completion:(void (^) (NSArray * result,NSError * error))completionBlock{

    _completionHandlers[PDFFile] = completionBlock;
    NSString *FileBrowserRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?PDFFile=%@",kIP,PDFFile];
    NSURL *JSONURL = [NSURL URLWithString:FileBrowserRequestString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:JSONURL];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                  {
                                      NSError *myError;
                                      NSArray *tableArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&myError]];

                                      completionBlock(tableArray,myError);
                                      [_completionHandlers removeObjectForKey:PDFFile];
                                  }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

where `_completionHandlers` is a `NSMutableDictionary` defined in your class.

Comment: Trying this now

Comment: This doesn't smell right; `dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` should be retaining/copying its completion handler—it wouldn't be a very good async API if it didn't (and if nothing else, the blocks it uses internally should capture the completion handler, causing a retain). And its completion handler should be capturing `completionBlock`. I at least have never had an issue doing this sort of thing.

Comment: This does not work I am still getting the same error